# Laravel braintree repeat request and race condition

Tags: laravel, race-condition, braintree, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a project with payment and subscriptions braintree.I need protection from repeated requests for user subscription. They occur, for example, when you repeatedly press the submit button. The subscription creation function consists of two parts - a request to braintree to create a subscription and then saving the subscription in the local database. During the long query to braintree there is a race condition occured.

**An important condition:**

- A user can only have one active subscription. The subscribed user
  should not be able to subscribe again

Code of creating subscription:

```
public function createSubscription($request)
{   

    if (isset($request['payment_method_nonce'])) {
        $gatewayCustomer = $this->findOrCreateCustomer();
        $this -> createPaymentMethod($request['payment_method_nonce'], $gatewayCustomer);
    }

    $trial_ends_at = isset($request['trial_ends_at']) ? $request['trial_ends_at'] : null;

    $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request["plan_id"]);


    if (!empty($this->defaultCard)) {
        $gatewaySubscription =  $this -> createGatewaySubscription($plan, $trial_ends_at);
    } 

    $subscription = $this->subscriptions()->create([
        'plan_id' => $plan->id,
        'trial_ends_at' => $trial_ends_at,
        'gateway_id' => isset($gatewaySubscription) ? $gatewaySubscription -> id : null,
        'card_id' => isset($this->defaultCard) ? $this->defaultCard->id : null,
    ]);
}
```

What solution can there be?

Lock user after start of createSubscription() method working? With users table locked_at column ? With Cache saving locked status for several minutes?

Comment: Instead of trying to solve this at the backend, why not solve it on the frontend? Just a simple thing such as disabling the submit button when the request is in process should do the trick?

Comment: More reliability and secure on backend. May be several tabs and browser exemplar with this form submitted. User and admin in one time as example... But double subscription in  braintree for one customer unacceptable!

Comment: In that case, I think you need to solve it on both the frontend and the backend. Also, I would recommend using [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing) It has a Braintree implementation out of the box

Comment: No i need more custom and flexible functional not laravel cashier. I can write my own cashier

Comment: Sure, good luck

Comment: Why not? I took as a basis classes of cashier and refactoring this. All works. But i whant prevent race conditions. I think i need mutex with memcache...

Comment: Find this solution $sem = sem_get(1234, 1);
if (sem_acquire($sem)) {
    //successful lock, go ahead
    sem_release($sem);
} else {
    //Something went wrong...
}